# Zonas de cobertura con Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema, y es que estoy desarrollando un mapa de áreas de cobertura en google maps y hasta el momento he logrado dibujar y definir muchas áreas en el mapa. En el código que les voy a compartir a continuación solo he dejado 3 zonas por motivos de ejemplo y usos de demostración.

Lo que debería hacer mi código es que cada vez que el marcador de Google Maps abandona el polígono rojo, su valor se vuelve falso arrojando una alerta.

```js
function sueltala() {
  Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: '¡Información importante!',
    text: 'Something went wrong!',
    footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
  })
}
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
window.onload = function init() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var
      contentCenter = '<span class="infowin">Center Marker (draggable)</span>',
      contentA = '<span class="infowin">Marker A (draggable)</span>',
      contentB = '<span class="infowin">Marker B (draggable)</span>';
    var
      latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
      latLngCMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
      latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
      latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -93),
      coords = [
        [
          [-89.19868711734125, 13.69215075483513],
          [-89.19807557368586, 13.691410653984653],
          [-89.19831965470621, 13.690871212812844],
          [-89.19834915900537, 13.69033177040379],
          [-89.19825796389887, 13.690128501928752],
          [-89.19697050357172, 13.690097229840053],
          [-89.19645551944086, 13.69013371394311],
          [-89.19598345065424, 13.690670550805194],
          [-89.19385914111444, 13.691295990264242],
          [-89.19233564639399, 13.691963123853995],
          [-89.19868711734125, 13.69215075483513],
          [-89.19868711734125, 13.69215075483513],
          [-89.19868711734125, 13.69215075483513]
        ],
        [
          [-89.19570795712826, 13.673281378361137],
          [-89.19570795712826, 13.673281378361137],
          [-89.19570795712826, 13.673281378361137],
          [-89.19654480634091, 13.673281378361137],
          [-89.19667355237362, 13.671175564389776],
          [-89.19562212643979, 13.6697786279033],
          [-89.1954075497186, 13.670612620832053],
          [-89.19602982221005, 13.67232229710495],
          [-89.19570795712826, 13.673281378361137]
        ],
        [
          [-89.18643520663386, 13.704821815720464],
          [-89.18654249499446, 13.703946250391347],
          [-89.1831092674554, 13.703550160242049],
          [-89.18302343676692, 13.70413387180797],
          [-89.18403194735652, 13.70430064627475],
          [-89.18403194735652, 13.704592501306768],
          [-89.1865854103387, 13.704842662474233],
          [-89.18643520663386, 13.704821815720464],
          [-89.18643520663386, 13.704821815720464]
        ]
      ],
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: latLngCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
      }),
      markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLngCMarker,
        title: 'Center of Circle',
        map: map,
        draggable: true
      }),
      infoCenter = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentCenter
      }),
      markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLngA,
        title: 'A',
        map: map,
        label: 'A',
        draggable: true
      }),
      infoA = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentA
      }),
      markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLngB,
        title: 'B',
        map: map,
        label: 'B',
        draggable: true
      }),
      infoB = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentB
      })
      // exemplary setup:
      // Assumes that your map is signed to the var "map"
      // Also assumes that your marker is named "marker"
      ,
      /* circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      clickable: false,
      // metres
      radius: 100000,
      fillColor: '#fff',
      fillOpacity: .6,
      strokeColor: '#313131',
      strokeOpacity: .4,
      strokeWeight: .8
      }); */
      bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
      var polygonCoords = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < coords[i].length; j++) {
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[i][j][1], coords[i][j][0])
        bounds.extend(pt);
        polygonCoords.push(pt);
      }
      // Construct the polygon.
      circle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: polygonCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
      });
    };
    // attach circle to marker
    circle.bindTo('center', markerCenter, 'position');
    google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds = function() {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      this.getPaths().forEach(function(path) {
        path.forEach(function(point) {
          bounds.extend(point);
        });
      });
      return bounds;
    };
    var
      // get the Bounds of the circle
      bounds = circle.getBounds()
      // Note spans
      ,
      noteA = jQuery('.bool#a'),
      noteB = jQuery('.bool#b');
    noteA.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerA.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
    noteB.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerB.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
    // get some latLng object and Question if it's contained in the circle:
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'dragend', function() {
      latLngCenter = markerCenter.position;
      noteA.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerA.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
      noteB.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerB.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'dragend', function() {
      latLngA = markerA.position;
      noteA.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerA.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function() {
      latLngB = markerB.position;
      noteB.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerB.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'click', function() {
      infoCenter.open(map, markerCenter);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', function() {
      infoA.open(map, markerA);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'click', function() {
      infoB.open(map, markerB);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'drag', function() {
      infoCenter.close();
      noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
      noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'drag', function() {
      infoA.close();
      noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'drag', function() {
      infoB.close();
      noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
    });
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #fff;
}

#note {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .3em;
  10px;
  background: #009ee0;
}

.bool {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #313131;
}

.info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

.infowin {
  color: #313131;
}

#title,
.bool {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>SAMPLE SITE</title>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    WebFontConfig = {
      google: {
        families: ['Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800', 'Poppins:300,400,500,600,700']
      }
    };
    (function(d) {
      var wf = d.createElement('script'),
        s = d.scripts[0];
      wf.src = 'assets/js/webfont.js';
      wf.async = true;
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })(document);
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Plugins CSS File -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Main CSS File -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCA3CvqkU5D5dLfADaABJi3OxjoWL64keA&callback=initMap&libraries=places,geometry,drawing&v=weekly" defer></script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="note">
    <span id="title">&raquo;Inside the circle?&laquo;</span>
    <hr />
    <span class="info">Marker <strong>A</strong>: <span id="a" class="bool"></span></span> &larr;&diams;&rarr; <span class="info">Marker <strong>B</strong>: <span id="b" class="bool"></span></span>
  </div>
  <div id="map">test</div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
```

El mapa que tengo ya desarrollado tiene zonas en color rojo y otras en color azul, la idea principal es de que cuando el marcador de google maps se coloque sobre un marcador de color rojo este indique al usuario mediante un alert que la zona esta bloqueada, caso contrario lo seria posicionar el marcador sobre una zona de color azul.

Espero puedan ayudarme pues llevo mucho tiempo intentando esto y no logro concretarlo.

Comment: Si no entiendo mal el problema, tienes que determinar si una coordenada está dentro de un polígono o no. Según creo no hay un método en la api que lo haga, y no es muy sencillo hacerlo manualmente. Te recomiendo que busques algún algoritmo o librería de javascript que lo haga.

Comment: @Emeeus Comentarte que en realidad lo que tengo que hacer es mostrar al usuario un alert cuando coloque el marcador dentro de las zonas colo rojo en el mapa, tienes idea de como puedo hacer eso o recomendarme un framework que haga esto.